# Lighthouse audit: JS reduce execution time

Tags: performance, query-performance, lighthouse

Thanks lots in advance.
In google's  lighthouse report, there's a section called "Reduce JavaScript execution time".

In this section, there are few scripts like *jquery.min.js* w/ associated "Total CPU Time", "Script Evaluation", "Script Parse" columns.

In this section, there's also the page (for which I was running the report): **[www.abc.com/cards/](http://www.abc.com/cards/)**

What javascript is this referring to and how can I reduce the "Total CPU Time", "Script Evaluation", "Script Parse" values.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an over simplified explanation as there are loads of idiosyncrasies in how JavaScript runs in the browser but it should give a decent idea.

Script parse time is the time it takes for the browser to read the whole file and "understand" what is in it ready for the compilation / evaluation part

Script evaluation time is the time taken between parsing the script and loading the script into memory / executing the script. This is where the browser attempts to optimise code ready for execution.

Total CPU time is the total CPU time (on the main thread) that the script used including parsing, evaluation, compiling and running any functions.

Comment: Thanks lots Graham; deeply appreciated. 
Will you know what script "www.abc.com/cards/" (the page that I was running the report on) refers to?

Comment: I do not know what you mean as that just takes me to a 404 not found. I thought that was an example URL. Is that the URL you ran the report on or did you run it on another URL? Also is that a shorter version of the URL (i.e. is it missing parameters).

Comment: thanks lots Graham again; deeply appreciated.
That was just an example url.
Sorry was not clear.
Any page that you run the report on seems to have it.
If you run report on "www.airbnb.com" or "www.bankofamerica.com", within "Reduce JavaScript execution time" section, you will see "https://www.airbnb.com".
Don't understand which script that is referring to?

Comment: ahhh, so that is referring to any scripts served from that origin (so any files served from the domain) as well as inline scripts on the page within `<script>` tags.